# fstring quotes scope vscode theme

Tags: visual-studio-code, scope, vscode-extensions, tmlanguage

I'm using a vscode customized theme that I changed to fit my needs, which I based on github dark for scopes. I'm finally in a spot I find it nice looking but I have a problem with fstring quotes, they simply don't get colored.

[image: Prints sequence]

I've tried some scopes and just the `punctuation.definition.string.begin/end` worked. When I tried using the `meta.fstring.python` it changed the whole string color, quotes and text inside. The strange is that the raw (r"") strings work. Also there's this bug with the {var} inside the raw one.

Tried [MagicPython](https://github.com/MagicStack/MagicPython) to see if any of their [Scopes](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MagicStack/MagicPython/master/misc/scopes) work, but it didn't

Any suggestions as to which should I use to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean "they simply don't get colored"? Which part of the screenshot are you talking about? It looks pretty coloured to me.

Comment: Why would `{var}` work inside straight raw strings? That construct doesn't have any special meaning in Python. It only works in regular strings (using string formatting) and f-strings. It's working in your last line because it's an f-string, not because it's a raw string.

Comment: @user look at the quotation marks. In the first 3 strings, the quote marks are a different color than the string contents. In the last two f-strings, they're not.

Comment: @MattDMo ah my apologies. I should have read more carefully!

Comment: @MattDMo I see, I didn't know about that, I apologise, thank you for explaining. And it's as Matt said, the fstring quotes didn't get colored.

Comment: Which Python syntax/plugin are you using?

Comment: Is there a way to check that? I think it is Pylance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work, had to specify the scope more explicitly.

The order of the scopes in the Visual Studio Code theme file determines the order in which they are applied. To make the `punctuation.definition.string.begin.python` scope take precedence over the `string.quoted.single.python` scope, you need to ensure that the former is defined after the latter.

However, even if the scopes are defined in the correct order, there can be a conflict if one of the scopes is more specific than the other. In this case, the `string.quoted.single.python` scope is more specific than the `punctuation.definition.string.begin.python` scope, so it will be applied instead. To address this, you can make the `punctuation.definition.string.begin.python` scope more specific by including `string.quoted.single.python` as a sub-scope.

```
    "punctuation.definition.string.begin.python string.interpolated.python",
    "punctuation.definition.string.begin.python string.quoted.double.python",
    "punctuation.definition.string.begin.python string.quoted.single.python",
    "punctuation.definition.string.end.python string.interpolated.python",
    "punctuation.definition.string.end.python string.quoted.double.python",
    "punctuation.definition.string.end.python string.quoted.single.python"
```

This way, it works

[image]